# refrormating the output of print and save it as a data.frame in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to reformat the output of `print` and save that as a `data.frame`. My **desired output** is shown below.

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this goal in BASE R? 
 (A functional answer is highly appreciated.)

```
dat1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/bus.csv")

fit3 <- factanal(dat1, 9, data = dat1, rotation = "varimax")

print(fit3[[2]], cutoff = .5, digits = 2)
```

**Desired output (shown partially to save space):**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we convert to `table`, can use `melt` from `reshape2`

```
out <- reshape2::melt(as.table(fit3[[2]]))
head(out)
#  Var1    Var2       value
#1   Q1 Factor1  0.22366038
#2   Q2 Factor1  0.17247766
#3   Q3 Factor1  0.13137496
#4   Q4 Factor1  0.05196747
#5   Q5 Factor1 -0.02885493
#6   Q6 Factor1  0.24943613
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
transform(subset(as.data.frame.table(fit3[[2]]), Freq >= 0.5),
      Var2 = sub("\\D+", "", Var2))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207717/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-refrormating-the-output-of-print-and-save-it-as-a).